# Java: having multiple objects of one class

Tags: java, class, variables, object, methods

I am having an issue where each class has multiple objects, it is a mess of objects being created of each class and I am having errors. The 4 class files are Main, Game, Updates Building, I will show the constructors of each class and hopefully someone can help me show how to create multiple objects of one class. There are variables in game that I need to access from update and building but when I try errors are returned. How do I access the variables in game from both update and building

Main:

```
public class Main 
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game newGame = new Game();

        newGame.setupGame();
        Game.isRunning=true;
        newGame.gameLoop();

    }

}
```

Game:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private Scanner input;
    private Updates getUpdates;

    public Game(){
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.getUpdates = new Updates(this);
    }
int happyness;
double money;
int population = 1000000;

}
```

Updates

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Updates {

    private Scanner input;

    private Game newGame;

    Building buildBuilding = new Building();

    public Updates(Game newGame){
        this.newGame = newGame;
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Building

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Building {

    public Building(){

        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    private Scanner input;
}
```

I want the building class to be able to access the variables in main as well as the update class being able to access the variables in main.

Comment: Which variables of Building class ? input ?

Comment: I have read it 3 times and don't understand what you want. What errors do you have? And what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Having several scanners all over `System.in` feels wrong to me.  I doubt that this is your problem, but it seems like it's asking for trouble to me.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDITED]**

Change in **Updates** class:

```
Building buildBuilding;

public Updates(Game newGame){
    this.newGame = newGame;
    this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    this.buildBuilding = new Building(newGame);
}
```

You have accidentally called an empty constructor, so

```
public Building(Game newGame){

        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.newGame = newGame;
    }
```

was never called, and therefore `input` was NULL.

Comment: No, I know how to get the variables but when I try to do it from 2 different classes at the same time [accessing variables from game from 2 seperate classes], i get an error

Comment: Could you provide a runnable code in which error occurs? I cannot induce the error with this small sample.

Comment: Firstly, this code is not compiling. There is no an empty constructor in the **Building** class, and it is being called from the **Updates** class. I have added it and the output is _Goverment: 1=Democracy 2=monarchy 3=dictatorship_

And now my computer is stuck. My RAM is destroyed. :D I will return with the answer as soon as I restart my machine... :D

Comment: I do not get it. You are looping while **government** not 1 or 2 two or 3, and then you check again inside the loop is it 1 or 2 or 3. Once this **while (!goverment.equals("1")||!goverment.equals("2")||!goverment.equals("3")){** becomes true, the loop will end.

I see now, it is not RAM, I should enter something...